How do you create a rotational matchedGeometryEffect in SwiftUI?
I have an HStack and a VStack, both containing the same views. By clicking a button, I want to create a rotational matchedGeometryEffect, where the gray background of a ZStack rotates in the direction of the HStack, and vice versa — the HStack rotates to align with the VStack(both in the shortest distance). I started working on the rotationEffect, but since I have text, I can't use it directly. I want the text to stay upright during the rotation, but I also want it to move along an arc during the transition. The gray background should rotate normally, while I want the red circle to be the center of the rotation, not the center of the view itself. I wrote some code, but there's an issue: during the transition, the background color fades in and out. I’d like the color to remain consistent throughout the transition. Can we make this rotational matchedGeometryEffect?
 struct MyView: View {
    
    @Namespace private var animationNamespace
    @State private var isVertical: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Spacer()
            
            ZStack {
                
                if isVertical {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { index in
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
                                .foregroundColor((index == 0) ? Color.red : Color.black)
                                .overlay(Text(String(describing: index)).foregroundColor(.white))
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "\(index)", in: animationNamespace)
                                .transition(.scale(scale: 1))
                                
                        }
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { index in
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
                                .foregroundColor((index == 0) ? Color.red : Color.black)
                                .overlay(Text(String(describing: index)).foregroundColor(.white))
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "\(index)", in: animationNamespace)
                                .transition(.scale(scale: 1))

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .bold()
            .padding()
            .background(Color.gray)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2.0), value: isVertical)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Toggle Layout") {
                isVertical.toggle()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


I don't think rotationEffect is completely out of the question. Your text can just be rotated in the other direction, so it still looks upright in the end. The real difficult part is rotating about the red view.

matchedGeometryEffect cannot match the orientation of views. The optional parameter of matchedGeometryEffect takes a MatchedGeometryProperties, which only has position, size, and both (frame).
Here is an implementation using a similar approach to Benzy Neez's answer, i.e. rotating the text in the opposite direction to keep the text upright.
struct UnitPointInStackKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: UnitPoint? = nil
    
    static func reduce(value: inout UnitPoint?, nextValue: () -> UnitPoint?) {
        if let next = nextValue() {
            value = next
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {

   @State private var isVertical: Bool = false
   @State private var rotationAnchor = UnitPoint.center

   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Spacer()
           ZStack {
               HStack {
                   numbers
               }
               .padding()
               .background {
                   Color.gray
                       .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 10))
               }
               .coordinateSpace(name: "stack")
               .onPreferenceChange(UnitPointInStackKey.self) {
                   if let value = $0 {
                       rotationAnchor = value
                   }
               }
               .rotationEffect(.degrees(isVertical ? 90 : 0), anchor: rotationAnchor)
           }
           .bold()
           .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2.0), value: isVertical)
           
           Spacer()
           
           Button("Toggle Layout") {
               isVertical.toggle()
           }
       }
       .padding()
   }
    
    var numbers: some View {
        ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { index in
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
                .foregroundColor((index == 0) ? Color.red : Color.black)
                .overlay {
                    Text(String(describing: index)).foregroundColor(.white)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(isVertical ? -90 : 0))
                }
                .overlay {
                    GeometryReader { geo in
                        if index == 0, let stackFrame = geo.bounds(of: .named("stack")) {
                            let textFrame = geo.frame(in: .named("stack"))
                            let unitPoint = UnitPoint(
                                x: textFrame.midX / stackFrame.width,
                                y: textFrame.midY / stackFrame.height
                            )
                            Color.clear
                                .preference(key: UnitPointInStackKey.self, value: unitPoint)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

The key differences are:

I am using a preference key to calculate a UnitPoint representing the center of rotation, so it works even if you don't know how long the view is beforehand.
the rotation is purely a visual effect - the frame of the view does not change
the center of rotation does not move


I tried to remove the optional PreferenceKey, but it didn’t work well. For your code to work, it needs to be optional; otherwise, the red view won’t be the center point. Could you explain what’s happening? Why does the optional version work correctly while the non-optional one doesn’t? Also, I think you could achieve this with .background((index == 0) ? GeometryReader { ... } : nil). Also for ZStack this: .background(Color.gray.cornerRadius(10.0))

@swiftPunk See my answer here for why the preference key is optional. reduce must fulfill an invariant, and I think making it optional is the most convenient way of doing that. Note that cornerRadius is deprecated in newer versions.

Using .matchedGeometryEffect for this transition may be difficult.
A simpler approach is perhaps to apply a .rotationEffect to the HStack and then an inverse .rotationEffect to the underlying text fields. If you want the rotated view to flow normally in the layout then you might want to adjust the .frame too.
You mentioned a red circle to be used as the center of rotation, but I couldn't see any red circle in your example. However, if you need to change the center of rotation, an anchor parameter can be added to the .rotationEffect.
HStack {
    ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { index in
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
            .foregroundStyle(index == 0 ? .red : .black)
            .overlay {
                Text(String(describing: index))
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(isVertical ? -90 : 0))
            }
    }
}
.bold()
.padding()
.background {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
        .fill(.gray)
}
.rotationEffect(.degrees(isVertical ? 90 : 0))
.frame(maxWidth: isVertical ? 60 : .infinity, maxHeight: isVertical ? .infinity : 60)
.border(.red)
.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2.0), value: isVertical)



EDIT If in fact you want to rotate around the red item, then you need to compute what fraction of the width this position represents. This is not difficult if you know the size of the spacing and padding. It is then important to use .topLeading as the alignment when setting the frame.
Here is the fully updated example to show it working this way:
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var isVertical: Bool = false
    let nItems = 11
    let itemSize: CGFloat = 20
    let spacing: CGFloat = 10
    let padding: CGFloat = 16

    private var largeDimension: CGFloat {
        (CGFloat(nItems) * itemSize) + (CGFloat(nItems - 1) * spacing) + (padding * 2)
    }

    private var smallDimension: CGFloat {
        itemSize + (padding * 2)
    }

    private var xOffsetRedItemCenter: CGFloat {
        padding + (itemSize / 2)
    }

    private var anchor: UnitPoint {
        UnitPoint(x: xOffsetRedItemCenter / largeDimension, y: 0.5)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Spacer()

            HStack(spacing: spacing) {
                ForEach(0..<nItems, id: \.self) { index in
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: itemSize, height: itemSize)
                        .foregroundStyle(index == 0 ? .red : .black)
                        .overlay {
                            Text(String(describing: index))
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                .rotationEffect(.degrees(isVertical ? -90 : 0))
                        }
                }
            }
            .bold()
            .padding(padding)
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .fill(.gray)
            }
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(isVertical ? 90 : 0), anchor: anchor)
            .frame(
                width: isVertical ? smallDimension : largeDimension,
                height: isVertical ? largeDimension : smallDimension,
                alignment: .topLeading
            )
            .border(.red)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2.0), value: isVertical)

            Spacer()

            Button("Toggle Layout") {
                isVertical.toggle()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}



Thanks for answer, I think there is an issue about anchor in your codes, I want the anchor be on 0 the red view, I could not make it, I used .rotationEffect(.degrees(isVertical ? 90 : 0), anchor: .leading) it is still not what I wanted but it is better than nothing.

I chose the Sweeper answer; it seems to fit the question better. I hope you don't mind.
